# Meomo's path data

Tags: backup

My phone has problem and I get the following error for many programs:

[image]

Now, I want to refactor my Android, But I need to save my Memo's information.

 Where are my Memo's information?

**UPDATE:**

I think my data exists on my disk, Because when I open my memos, I see the following data:

[image]

I found ShareMemo directory, But it doesn't contain of my information.

Comment: By "Memo", did you mean Samsung's Memo app? We have [some questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=samsung+memo) related to it, perhaps some of them might help. Otherwise, please mention the device model and Android version.

Comment: Regarding your updates, apps' data are usually stored in Internal Storage that cannot be viewed without root access. Please refer to the duplicate question.

Comment: Do I have to root my cell phone?

Comment: If you attempt to root your device all of your data would be deleted. All you can do is to see if the app offers an export or backup option. Otherwise, see if it can be backed up using adb. Otherwise, you are out of luck.